# Lock Keys extension in Ubuntu 20-04

Tags: gnome

I have installed

1. Gnome-shell-integration in Firefox  and
2. chrome-gnome-shell   --in Ubuntu 20-04

in order to install from Gnome Extensions the extension Lock Keys.
I know that I should be shown a picture of it showing a switch that I simply have to put 'on', but I always get a picture with 'download' and 'shell version' instead.
I have pictures of both situations, but have trouble sending them along, sorry.

Installing the extension by hand in /home/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look on this weblink https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/install-gnome-extensions-on-ubuntu for gnome-extensions.

The manual way of installation worked for me in my Ubuntu 20.04

[image]

for Ubuntu 20.04, download extension version number 45 which is latest as of now.

Once downloaded. from the downloaded location.

run,

```
gnome-extensions install -f lockkeysvaina.lt.v45.shell-extension.zip
```

Restart the gnome-shell with Alt+F2 r method if you are on X11 or logout and login in if you are on "Wayland"

Enable the extension.

[image]

Comment: I followed your steps; after the zip landed in Downloads I ran *gnome-extensions install -f lockkeysvaina.lt.v45.shell-extension.zip*  Terminal says: *Error in opening file /home/fre/lockkeysvaina.lt.v45.shell-extension.zip: file or folder doesn't exist* --also after I put the zip by hand in  */home/fre/*  My Ubuntu 20-04 runs under Wayland.   What is going wrong?

Comment: "Once Downloaded" I mean.. from the first screenshot, once you choose 3.36 and 45 the extension starts downloading. If you have already downloaded. This download will choose a different name. Based on that name change the command.

Comment: `gnome-extensions install -f DOWNLOADEDZIPFILENAME`

Comment: Once you downloaded the zip file. 1st step is to install the extension with `gnome-extensions install -f DOWNLOADEDZIPFILENAME`. 2nd step is to logout and login because you are using Wayland. 3rd step is to enable the extension either via GUI tools or with command line `gnome-extensions enable lockkeys@vaina.lt`

Comment: I don't understand; the command had the exact name of the download. Once I ran it I got the same answer as mentioned beforehand. What I had not done yet was running *gnome-extensions enable lockkeys@vaina.lt*, but that didn't work.

Comment: Hi, if the first command i.e `gnome-extensions install -f DOWNLOADEDZIPFILENAME` is successful then only above command works i.e `gnome-extensions enable lockkeys@vaina.lt`. I think you are not running the first command from the downloaded location/Directory

Comment: I just discovered a mistake. In '~' I have a folder 'fre' where I had put the zip in. The extension is working just fine now. Thank you for your patience.